# Cannot access Fragment in nested RecyclerView

Tags: android-studio, android-glide, nestedrecyclerview

I want to load an image from an URL into an imageView within a nested RecyclerView. I use the Glide library for that.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull InnerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(movieList.get(position).getName());

    Glide.with(context).load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + movieList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
}
```

I pass the Activity context through the recyclerViews, but when I want to run the app, it fails with this message:

> error: cannot access Fragment

> Glide.with(context).load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + movieList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.imageView);

> class file for android.support.v4.app.Fragment not found

What can I  do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass activity context to the adapter, instead do this

```
 Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + movieList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
```

Comment: It still fails with the same error

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or its link please?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/yQv31CB